# Can i use MS SharePoint 2016 for a custom web app solution

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I have a question regarding the best solution to adopt for a client. My client has an existing Access

database with tables, queries, reports and lots of them! He requires an application/solution that will :

```
allow it to be used online/cloud.
allow the application users to login and access only their record data.
allow my client to have a main-admin account to login too and adminster all client accounts.
allow the application users to add a text box via a form to add a new field to the table
allow application users to upload documents against a record
```

Heres my dilemma; as a PHP/Open Source developer i could write an application which does all of this; having already used a 3rd party program to convert his Access dB to MySQL (though i will have to manually convert the Access Queries forms to MySQL Views.

This is my preference since i have total control and confidence with the dev tools i'll use. Down side is it will take absolutely ages because of the number of tables and queries. Alternatively, i recently read about MS Sharepoint which i know nothing about other than what i read. SharePoint looks like it could handle this solution very easily especially the MS Access stuff, Microsoft now 
as of 2018 recommend using 'PowerApps' for building Access Apps in sharepoint. It all looks quite do-able but i'm not a MS aficionado and dont want to get in 'out-of-my-depth'.

Having done (and enjoyed) many years of MS VB development up to about 5 years ago, i know Sharepoint will allow you to work at a level which requires less Programming skills and more Power-user skillsets.

Can any one advise which they think would be the best route, im not asking for the finite detail - just a pointer from anyone that uses Sharepoint and knows its capabilities beyond the little i've read. Im looking to invest some time into learning it for future projects as it looks great; but for this project isnt it a little to simple???

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Access is a Windows application - and therefore not browser based.  There is no port to html technology - it is a complete re-write.

For geographically distance users - as with any Windows application - the available solution is the Remote Desktop technology.

It is / would be unusual for any application to allow the end users to redefine the table structure.  Thus the idea of adding new fields to a table is not feasible but perhaps one is using the wrong terminology and intends instead to be adding new records to the table - which would be routine.

The other features are all do-able in Access.

For years we've seen users wanting a magic transform from their Access Windows application to a web based application.  It simply does not exist.

Comment: Hi, Not really true - i have already assessed that Sharepoint CAN handle this convertion of data there a Youtube videos and info on the MS sites showing how this is being done today (in fact its pretty much defacto by now). I was really looking for info from an experienced Sharepoint Dev who could assess whether Sharepoint can handle the tasks i require. As i said i can write the whole thing is PHP/Mysql/HTML5/jQuery etc etc but Sharepoint appears to offers much quicker, cohesive solutions without having to re-invent the wheel so to speak.